# wso2 api management 2.0 production cluster deployment architecture

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are designing wso2 apim 2.0 cluster deployment architecture, from [2.0 clustering](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0), we just found distribution deployment description, so

1. Is the wso2 apim gateway 2.0 cluster same with 1.10?
2. Any recommendation for system CPU/MEMORY requirement?
3. wso2 apim 2.0 has traffic manager, how to cluster it?
4. For store/publisher, how to cluster them?
5. When integration with APIM Analytics, do we just need to config gateway workers?

Comment: BTW, Is SVN-Based Deployment Synchronizer MUST for wso2 gateway cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There are configuration changes, and also new configs, in gateways. But [gateway clustering](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+the+Gateway) has not been changed.

2) See [Installation Prerequisites](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Installation+Prerequisites) and [Tuning Performance](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Tuning+Performance)

3) There is no public document yet. It'll be there soon. Until now, you can cluster it in the same way gateways are clustered.

4) Store and publisher should be in the same cluster.

5) Gateway workers, store and publisher

**Update**:

About Dep-Sync: In gateway worker-manager setup, we only publish API synapse files to manager node, and then use dep-sync to copy those APIs to gateway workers. You can use anything that can sync artifacts between nodes instead of SVN based dep-sync. (eg. rsync)

Comment: thx! Is SVN-Based Deployment Synchronizer MUST for wso2 gateway cluster?  and from [cluster in amzone](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager+in+Amazon+Web+Services), it seems just gateway cluster used manager+worker mode, is it recommended?

Comment: From [Separating the Worker and Manager Nodes](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Separating+the+Worker+and+Manager+Nodes#SeparatingtheWorkerandManagerNodes-Patterns), It said that Worker/Manager separation is usually done for the Gateway, but can be done for the Publisher and Store as well.

Comment: Updated answer. Since pub/store are UIs, you don't need worker-manager separation for them.